# iOS 7: UITabBarItem image crops at bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a UITabBar with 4 tabs. 3/4 tabs have a title and an image. I'd like to show only an image in the first tab. It works on simulator good, but on iPhone it looks like the screenshot. It crops at the bottom. Icon sizes: 46x42 for 2,3 and 4th icons (retina size), and 92x80 for the 1st icon for retina size.

### The screenshot

[image]

### The code

```
_tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
_tabBarController.delegate=self;

_firstNavigationController = [[TypeCollectionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TypeCollectionViewController" bundle:nil];
_firstNavigationController.title = @"first";
firstNavigationController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0);
NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: firstNavigationController, secondNavigationController, thirdNavigationController, fNavigationController, nil];
_tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

[[[_tabBarController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first-icon.png"]];
[[[_tabBarController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:1] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"second-icon.png"]];
[[[_tabBarController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:2] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"third-icon.png"]];
[[[_tabBarController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:3] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"f-icon.png"]];

[_tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

[self.window setRootViewController:_tabBarController];
[[[_tabBarController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:nil];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

How to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: plz try once your image height for normal 48 and @2x 96

Comment: @MitsBhadeshiya nothing changed. What should be happened?

Answer (score 1):

**Note** : `UITabbarItem's` `image size` should be `32 pixel height`. Follow [Bars Guidleline](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html).

Also also `image` provided should be with `non-retina` as well as `retina image` to `tabbar item`.

What i mean here if you think that `only retina image` can be used for tabbar then in `non-retina device UI` might be `unexpected`.

Comment: No-no, I use 2 kinds of images. For retina and non-retina size for each icons. I know about bars guideline, but I have another application where I have big images in UITabBar.